# Windows Explorer - Delete entry in Context Menu

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I'm attempting a somewhat complex operation on Windows Explorer context menu.

I've got an encoding process, which i want to call upon any kind of file.
The idea is to right-click on a file, get the option in the context menu, and select.
This is relatively easy to do :

`HKCR "*\shell\encoding" "" "Encode with MyEncoder"`

It works.
The encoder produces *.encode extension files.
I want to decode these files using the same mechanism.
This is also quite straightforward :

`HKCR ".encode" "" "encoded.file"`

`HKCR "encoded.file\shell\decode" "" "Decode with MyEncoder"`

So now the basic mechanism is in place : Encode any file using context menu, decode these files also using context menu.

Now for the question :

The problem is : "Encode with MyEncoder" option also appears on *.encode file. It seems understandable, since this option has been made available for *any* file type. However, I don't want this option to be valid if the file extension is *.encode.

Is that possible to do, and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use Advanced Query Syntax to conditionalize your menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171.aspx#dynamic_behavior). For example, `AppliesTo` = `NOT System.FileExtension:=.encode`.

Comment: Now that you are here on SO I should know better than to answer questions like this. I should just wait until you can do it and get the answer right!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Don't worry. It's a relatively new feature, so I'm not surprised people aren't familiar with it.

Comment: @Raymond : Interesting. Is this syntax only valid for Windows Seven ?

Comment: New for Windows 7. For older versions of Windows, you will have to write an `IContextMenu` extension, which is a lot of work.